# Finding the coefficient "a" of a linear equation of the form Y = aX

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network

Suppose I have two sets, X and Y, and some preknown coefficient "a".

Set Y depends on X and "a" as follows:
Y = aX

```
import numpy as np

a = 2
X = np.random.randint(1, 10, 10)
Y = a * X

print(f"{X = }")
print(f"{Y = }")

>>> X = array([9, 2, 7, 8, 8, 9, 5, 8, 4, 1])
>>> Y = array([18,  4, 14, 16, 16, 18, 10, 16,  8,  2])
```

Task:
Using PyTorch toolkit find the coefficient "a" using only X and Y

What I tried to do and what the problem was:

I am trying to pass X[i] to a model and expect to get the coefficient a_pred from it. Then I find y_pred = a_pred * X[i]. Finally I compare y[i] and y_pred.
Obviously, the model does not "see" the relationship between a_pred, "a", y_pred and Y[i]. Hence the question: what should be the architecture of the model so that it can find the correct coefficient of "a"?

I'm just starting to learn PyTorch, and unfortunately, so far, I haven't found an unambiguous answer to this question. So far, it seems to me that the solution to this problem must be somehow related to GAN, but how exactly I unfortunately do not know

My current code:

```
import numpy as np
from torch.nn import Module, Linear, ReLU, Sequential, CrossEntropyLoss
from torch.optim import Adam
from torch import from_numpy

from random import randint


class FindParameter(Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FindParameter, self).__init__()
        self.layers = Sequential(
            Linear(1, 10),
            ReLU(),
            Linear(10, 100),
            ReLU(),
            Linear(100, 10),
            ReLU(),
            Linear(10, 1),
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.layers(input)


a = 5.0
x = []
y = []
train_dataset_size = 10000
for i in range(train_dataset_size):
    x.append(randint(0, 10000))
    y.append(x[i] * a)

X = [from_numpy(np.array([c], dtype=np.float32)) for c in x]
Y = [from_numpy(np.array([c], dtype=np.float32)) for c in y]
A = from_numpy(np.array([a], dtype=np.float32))

epochs = range(100)

model = FindParameter()
loss_f = CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)


for epoch in epochs:
    for x, y in zip(X, Y):
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        a_pred = model(x)
        y_pred = a_pred * x

        loss = loss_f(y_pred, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

Comment: If the relationsip is exact then just use ```a=Y[0]/X[0]```. If you want a best-fit to scattered data then just use ```a=sum( X * Y ) / sum( X * X )```

Comment: You just need a single Linear layer (no bias, no activation), nothing else. The weights of the Linear layer represent `a`.

Comment: In my experience Adam is unpredictable with these types of problems sometimes, you may want to try out SGD with a low learning rate.

Comment: @lastchance This is indeed a workable option for functions acting from R to R, but in the case of functions acting from M to M (in the case of Adamard multiplication), this method will unfortunately not work. I gave an example of the simplest case of what I need (multiplication of scalars)

Answer (score 1):

See that you have a very defined model you want to train: Y = a*X.

So your model architecture is just the parameter `a`, and the forward pass is just multiplying that parameter with the inputs.

Also, that model works in a regression format (the output is a continuous value), so cross-entropy (normally used for multi-class classification) is not the correct choice, instead a Mean Squared Error would make more sense (you want predicted outputs to be as close to the real ones).

Also also, the exercise asks you to use only the provided X and Y. In such case, and given that the model is so simple that only one value of `a` is the optimal solution (i.e. it is a convex optimization problem), you are better off just doing a single optimization step.

The following implements that:

```py
from torch.nn import Parameter
from torch.optim import Adam


class FindParameter(Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FindParameter, self).__init__()
        self.a = Parameter(data=1.0)

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.a * input


X = ...
Y = ...


model = FindParameter()
loss_f = MSELoss()
optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

epochs = 100

for epoch in epochs:
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    y_pred = model(X)

    loss = loss_f(y_pred, Y)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Answer (score 0):

We show in our R package 'cito' (which simplifies the training of NN) how you can use NN to optimize arbitrary functions (the only requirement is that they must be differentiable and written in Torch). Your question is similar to our [example](https://citoverse.github.io/cito/articles/D-Advanced_custom_loss_functions.html#example-3-using-cito-for-optimization-active-learning):

Simulate some data from a linear model (true slope = 2, true sigma = 0.4)

```
library torch
library(cito)  
X = runif(200)
Y = 2*X + rnorm(200, sd = 0.4)
df = data.frame(X = X, Y = Y)
```

Function we want to optimize (linear model):

```
Xt = torch_tensor(matrix(X))
Yt = torch_tensor(matrix(Y))

model_lm = function(par) {
  pred = Xt$matmul(par[,1,drop=FALSE])
  loss = -torch::distr_normal(pred, scale = torch::torch_exp(par[,2,drop=FALSE]))$log_prob(Yt)
  return(loss$mean())
}
```

The actual loss function:

```
custom_loss = function(pred, true, ...) {
  if(nrow(pred) > 1) return(torch_zeros(1L)) # disable loss calculation
  loss = model_lm(pred)
  return(loss)
}
```

X and Y values don't matter, number of columns in Y has to match the number of parameters we want to optimize, here two column, one for the slope parameter and one for the sigma parameter. We feed noise to our neural network and it predicts the two parameter (similar to the generator in a GAN):

```
noise = matrix(runif(300*5), 300, 5)
noise_y = matrix(runif(300*2), 300, 2)
df = data.frame(y1 = noise_y[,1], y2 = noise_y[,2], noise)
```

Fit the final model:

```
m = dnn(cbind(y1, y2)~., data = df, loss = custom_loss, batchsize = 1L, epochs = 20L, verbose = FALSE)
```

Results:

```
# Effect:
mean(predict(m)[,1])
#> [1] 2.02776
# SD
mean(exp(predict(m)[,2]))
#> [1] 0.3864421
```